# How to get last inserted 3 records with condition mysql

Tags: mysql, database

am adding  new record for every transaction( for ex; microfinance, today customer paid 300, then new record is inserted,tomorrow 500 again new record is inserted) thyen how can i get last 3 records based on customer id.

Comment: If you have an auto-increment column in your table you use order by `select * from table where customer_id=1 order by id desc limit 3`

Comment: are you using PDO, mysqli, ... ? both have a function to retrieve the last inserted id.

Comment: my table is:id             pass                  amount

Comment: id             passwors             amount

Comment: Have you checked my answer, if it helped please mark it as answer and upvote it so that it may help someone in the future and increases my reputation too

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Id
      ,Password
      ,Amount
      ,@curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM sample JOIN  (SELECT @curRow := 0) r 
where id=1 
order by Row_number
desc limit 3;
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c5c5/10)

Comment: how to get amount of last record into a ,amount of second record from last into b and 3 rd record amount from last into c

Comment: you want the amount of last record of a, b and c right??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3;
```

First, order your select using `ORDER BY` and then use `LIMIT` to get first records.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use `order by desc` customer id and get last 3 record with `limit 0,3`:

```
select * from tbname
order by customerid desc
limit 0,3
```