# How to get last 3 records

Tags: mysql, database

I am adding new record for every transaction

**For Example**:
 microfinance,

1. Today customer paid 300, then new record is inserted
2. tomorrow 500 again new record is inserted)

then how can i get last 3 records based on customer id.

table

```
ID               Password            Amount
1                  a                   200
2                  s                   500
1                  a                   100
3                  b                   200
1                  a                   300
1                  a                   300
```

there is no primary key

i want last inserted 3 records for `id=1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get last inserted 3 records with condition mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496604/how-to-get-last-inserted-3-records-with-condition-mysql)

Comment: You have answers to a previous copy of this question.

Comment: i have updated my answer you can check with that

Comment: not only last record. table contain duplicate id( means there is no primary key).i want last inserted 3 records of same id.

Comment: @user3260112 my solution is not based on primary key you can check with this

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,3
```

Comment: not this , it's giving last 3 records not based on id;                1                  a                    200
2                  s                      500
1                   a                   100

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id
      ,Password
      ,Amount
      ,@curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM sample JOIN  (SELECT @curRow := 0) r 
where id=1 
order by Row_number
desc limit 3;
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c5c5/10)